# Abrir VIewController iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Como faço para que a função abaixo (quando for clicado um item da barra de navegação) abra uma outra tela já criada no `Main.storyboard`?

```
@objc func infoTapped (sender:UIButton) {

}
```

Comment: Se quiser adicionar a barra de navegação a qualquer VC basta voce selecionar ele no Interface Builder e depois clica no Editor > Embed in > Navigation Controller. Não é necessário você esteja vindo de um que já tenha a barra de navegação.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tem duas formas.

Uma delas é criar uma segue no storyboard, atribuir a ela um identificador e, neste método chamar a função `performSegue(withIdentifier: IDENTIFICADOR, sender: self)`.

A outra é você instanciar o VC que quer chamar nesse método, mais ou menos assim:

```
if let destinationVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "IDENTIFICADOR_VC") {
        present(destinationVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: Olá, deu certo!!! Usei a segunda opção. Porém quando a minha VC abre não aparece a barra de navegação bem como o botão voltar. Como eu poderia resolver isso?

Comment: Para aparecer uma barra de navegação é necessário que o seu VC de origem seja um UINavigationViewController.

Comment: Sendo ele navigation, ao invés de chamar o "present", você dá um self.navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationVC, animated:true)

Comment: Legal, deu certo também!! mas agora a nova VC aparece com a barra e os botões que a barra contém lá na tela inicial, tem como eu os tirar (fazendo com que eles apareçam somente na barra da tela inicial)?

Comment: Tem sim. No método viewWillAppear, faz self.navigationController.setNavigationBarHidden pra true

Comment: Tentei isso: override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool){
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden = true
    } Mas diz que o setNavigation... é método

Comment: Tiago, sinceramente, acho interessante pa você começar a olhar a documentação e usar as dicas do próprio xcode. A assinatura do método "setNavigationBarHidden" é self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(hidden: Bool, animated: Bool), então a forma de setar ele pra true é: self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true) (o animated pouco importa se vai ser true ou false). Acho melhor pra você dar uma estudada na documentação ou vai precisar sempre recorrer a perguntas e de respostas prontas. ;)

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, concordo com vc, porém esse problema que parece ser bobo já tentei de inúmeras formas e não dá certo.. Já tinha tentado esse código que me passou, porém a barra toda desaparece, incluindo o botão voltar. Mas mesmo assim muito obrigado, me ajudou muito! Vou tentar novamente na documentação! ;)

Comment: Esse código realmente tira toda a barra e os botões. Como o botao de voltar faz parte da barra, se você some com a barra, os botões vão junto.

Comment: Pra deixar a tela original sem barra e a tela de destino com a barra, você usa esse código setando pra hidden na tela original e setando pra não hidden (false) na tela de destino

Comment: Aliás, você falou que está começando em Swift. Se você fala ingles, tem vários cursos que custam papo de 30 reais na udemy e ajudam muito!

Comment: Obrigado mais uma vez pela ajuda, mas já consegui resolver esse problema... já comprei alguns cursos lá, estou fazendo!